# Express-session reattach

Tags: node.js, authentication, express-session

I have an application with express-session@1.17.1, passport@0.3.2, and connect-redis@4.0.0. We manage the session of a user with cookies. There is a scenario when we need to let the user go to a different domain to complete the checkout process and come back. If we keep the cookie property to be strict the user's session is lost as it is unable to find the cookie, coming from 3rd party. A new session will be generated for the given user. There can be one way to handle this situation, which I can think of.

Here is my session configuration

```js
return session({
            genid: () => uuidv4(),
            store: redisStore,
            cookie: {
                maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 /* 30 days */,
                secure: true,
                sameSite: true,
                path: '/',
            },
            secure: true,
            sameSite: true,
            secret: '123',
            resave: false,
            name: 'prod',
            saveUninitialized: true,
        })(req, res, next);
```

Notice, I want to keep the `same site` property true, to prevent any CSRF. This also prevents cookies from valid third-party domains redirecting to our site.

1. Reattach the existing session with the session to a user coming back to the callback URL. This will require passing a session identifying token in the callback URL.

If I just pass the session-id in the callback URL, I can see the last session of the user and able to attach the. I don't think passing session-id is safe enough. I would like to know the correct way to do this.

Comment: Why is the cookie lost?  The cookie should be able to persist for as long as you want it to no matter what else the user does in the browser.  This is what cookies are usually used for.

Comment: In strict mode it is not persisting when coming from other domain. Is there a way?

Comment: One reason, why this might happens is, whenever a request without a cookie comes to the node server, the node server tries to set a new cookie, which is not the same as previous one. Thus the session is lost.

Comment: There's simply not enough information about what is actually happening here for us to help.  A browser doesn't just stop sending a cookie.  If the cookie is created with the right settings, it is sent every time (until it expires) when a request comes to the domain that the cookie is set on.